# Cordova - Add plugin dependency with variable

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, plugins

I am creating a plugin which needs other plugins as dependencies. So in my `plugin.xml` I have the following:

```
<dependency id="cordova-plugin-statusbar" version="~2.4.2" />
```

But imagine that to install this plugin I need a variable called `HELLO`. In a way that if you wanted to install this plugin you'd need to do:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar@2.4.2 --variable HELLO="A value"
```

So, how can I configure that variable this in my `plugin.xml` file? Is it possible?

Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

I have this now:

```
    <dependency id="cordova-plugin-googlemaps" version="2.4.4">
        <variable name="API_KEY_FOR_IOS" value="XXX" />
        <variable name="API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID" value="XXX" />
    </dependency>
```

and I am getting this error:

```
Installing "cordova-plugin-googlemaps" for android
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-googlemaps': Error: Variable(s) missing: API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID
    at Object.mergeVariables (C:\Users\Dialogo\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v6.14.4\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\variable-merge.js:58:15)
    at C:\Users\Dialogo\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v6.14.4\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\install.js:315:44
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\Dialogo\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v6.14.4\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:854:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\Dialogo\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v6.14.4\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:883:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\Dialogo\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v6.14.4\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:816:13)
    at C:\Users\Dialogo\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v6.14.4\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:624:44
    at runSingle (C:\Users\Dialogo\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v6.14.4\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
    at flush (C:\Users\Dialogo\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v6.14.4\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

Comment: can you share your config.xml

Answer (score 1):

You can add a variable in your plugin like that :

```
 <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~2.4.2">
        <variable name="HELLO" value="{value}" />
</plugin>
```

But its in your config.xml and not plugin.xml

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I am getting an error. Could you check my edit?

Comment: you have this error when u install ?  change the name of the variable like that :`GOOGLE_MAPS_ANDROID_API_KEY`

Comment: I have that error when it's installing the googlemaps plugin. The way to install it via command line is "cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="xxxx"" That needs to be variable name, I can't change that bec I haven't made that googlemaps plugin

Comment: and you give the key ?

Comment: yes, the "xxxx" in the edit 1 is just to hide my apikey, but the value is my apikey

Comment: Can you try to add the plugin without key ?  and add in the plugin.xml the variable after install

Comment: I can't it forces me to set them since the begining

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192638/discussion-between-sam-and-wrong).

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for this plugin covers this [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4280)

You can try like this:

cordova -d plugin add /Users/your/path/here/cordova-plugin-statusbar --variable HELLO="A value"

To add multiple parameters simply keep adding '--variable VARNAME="VARVALUE"'